# Set Cinnamon as default startup on Live CD/DVD

Tags: command-line, uck

I have build an Ubuntu remix with UCK, Ubuntu Customization kit and have installed Cinnamon via PPA. Now I want the Live DVD to start with Cinnamon directly. 
How to do this ? Terminal command maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the installation is on hard disk and you want to run Live *CD/DVD* in cinnamon.

To run the Live CD and fetch Cinnamon from installation is, I would say, tricky. But it is still possible to get Cinnamon on Live boot:

1) Using `whoami` get your Live-boot username (usually **ubuntu**)

2) Using `passwd` set your Live-boot password. If it has some issues, delete the password by `-d` option, and set password

3) Install cinnamon now.

4) Log out, put your username there (whoami one), and from the menu (Gear in 11.* and 12.* while bottom of the page list for older versions), select "Cinnamon" instead of "Gnome"

5) Enjoy :)